# Evaluating $ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \Bigl[ \frac{1}{j^2} + \frac{1}{(j+1)^2} - \frac{2}{j} + \frac{2}{j + 1} \Bigr] $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

In order to calculate the variance of a random variable, I've come across this infinite sum

$$ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \Bigl[ \frac{1}{j^2} + \frac{1}{(j+1)^2} - \frac{2}{j} + \frac{2}{j + 1} \Bigr] $$

Distributing the summation operator and rearranging the last two terms, you'd obtain

$$ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j^2} + \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(j+1)^2} -2\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \Bigl( \frac{1}{j} - \frac{1}{j+1} \Bigr) $$

The first sum is equal to $\pi^2/6$, I know. And the last sum is telescopic, resulting in $-2(1) = -2$. It's this middle term that I don't know how to evaluate, even though I know it converges.

Comment: reindex the second sum. It is different from $\pi^2/6$ by a constant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint :**
$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(j+1)^2} = \sum_{j=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j^2} =  \left( \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j^2}\right)-1 $$